# cocoa: dispatch design pattern

Tags: cocoa, dispatch

```
-(void) test{
    for(Person *person in persons){
        __block CGPoint point;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            point = [self.myview personToPoint:person];
        });
        usePoint(point); // take a long time to run
    }
}
```

I need to run `personToPoint()` in the main queue to get the point, and `usePoint()` method doesn't need to run in main queue and take a long time to run. However, when running `usePoint(point)`, point has not been assigned value because using dispatch_async. If using dispatch_sync method, the program will be blocked. the how can I using point after it has been assigned?

UPDATE:
how to implement the pattern of the following code:

```
-(void) test{
    NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(Person *person in persons){
        __block CGPoint point;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            point = [self.myview personToPoint:person];
            [points addObject:point];
        });
    }
    usePoint(points); // take a long time to run
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following would work. You might also put the entire for loop inside one dispatch_async() and let the main thread dispatch all the usePoint() functions at once.

```
-(void) test{
    for(Person *person in persons){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CGPoint point = [self.myview personToPoint:person];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                usePoint(point); // take a long time to run
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Solution for Updated question:**

You use the same basic pattern as suggested above. That is you dispatch the stuff you need to do on the main thread to the main thread and then nest a dispatch back to a default work queue inside the main thread dispatch. Thus when the main thread finishes its work it will dispatch off the time consuming parts to be done elsewhere.

```
-(void) test{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (Person *person in persons){
            CGPoint point = [self.myview personToPoint:person];
            [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            usePoint(points); // take a long time to run
        });    
    });
}
```

Note that there was an error in your code as you can't add `CGPoint`'s to an `NSArray` since they are not objects. You have to wrap them in an `NSValue` and then unwrap them in `usePoint()`. I used an extension to `NSValue` that only works on iOS. On Mac OS X you'd need to replace this with `[NSValue valueWithPoint:NSPointToCGPoint(point)]`.